# Labeling an equation with letters

Tags: equations

Is there a way to label an equation with letters instead of numbers? 
For instance,

```
\begin{equation}
\label{Problem}
\phi'(t)=f(t, \phi(t)).
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Yes. Could you elaborate on the use-case? Do you want all equations labelled with letters or just some? What should the letter format be... (A), (B), ... or (a), (b), ... or something different altogether?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Please post complete code i.e. a small, compilable document. That is much more useful than a fragment.

Comment: @Nicolas How is this a duplicate? That question explicitly says *neither* a number *nor* a letter, which is not the case here. (The solution might be similar but that's a different issue.)

Comment: Do you want all equations labelled with letters or just some? Just some.

Answer (score 4):

With the `alphalph` package, after 26 equations, they become `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, etc.  If one uses `\alphalph`, the letters are in lowercase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\def\theequation{\AlphAlph{\value{equation}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply redefine the counter to display with letters with:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
```

If you want Uppercase letters use:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}
```

You can even use combined Letters and numbers. Incorporating the section number as a number, and the equation as a letter:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\Alph{equation}}
```

Full example...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}

\begin{document}

\section{Lower Case Letter}   
\begin{equation}
y=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^3
\end{equation}

\section{Upper Case Letter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}
\begin{equation}
y=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^3
\end{equation}

\section{Section number and Upper Case Letter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\Alph{equation}}
\begin{equation}
y=x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=x^3
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Of course this fails of you have more than 26 equations. You can do set the counter to 0 explicitly at the beginning of each section with `\setcounter{equation}{0}`. Then with the section number and letter option I mentioned above you can have 26 equations per section. 

The same follows logically for all levels of sectioning -- chapter, subsection etc.